# asset library (swc) does not reflect changes in flash project in fb

Tags: flash-builder, flashdevelop

I have created gui related components in flash professional and exported the swc and added this swc into my referenced libraries (by adding link to the swc) and I can create/reference to the symbols in my flash builder project.

Every thing is fine untill I modify something(MC) and export the swc the changes won't reflect immediately. This is somewhat understood, so I just use to restart FB so that the changes are reflected. This was working find until yesterday.

After making changes to symbols, nothing will reflect the changes

I restart the FB (which use to work till yesterday)
Refresh project, referenced libraries
Clear browser cache
Clean the project

I left home with frustration and today morning when I restarted the system it got reflected the changes. And now I did changes to the gui again and its the same problem.

I know there is one easy way which is to remove and add the swc reference from the project

I am pretty sure there could be much easy simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cache can sometimes not pick changes in SWC libraries (old known issue).

Solution, when you think this problem happens, is to "clean" the project. Both FlashBuilder and FlashDevelop let you clean the project from the Project main menu.

Comment: i forgot to add it initially, I added it now. It won;t work even if I clean the project